# Do I have to downgrade from iOS 7 Beta in order to get iOS 7 today?

Tags: upgrade, ios

I downloaded the iOS 7 Beta about a week ago and now I'm worried I'll have to downgrade in order to install iOS 7 that's being released today. Anyone have any insight? If I have to downgrade, what's the easiest way?

Comment: We're not a good place to discuss beta software. See the meta threads linked below for places where you can get assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download the GM seed from the Developer Portal to move off the Beta. This will once again be a complete clean and restore so make sure your backups are up to date before starting.

Barring any last minute showstoppers the GM build will be the released version.

Comment: Going forward, will the GM release behave the same as the standard version, in regards to OTA updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the iOS 7 final release over the beta without problems. Especially because Apple officially does not support downgrading at all.

Previously you had to download the release version as an image from the Apple developer site and install it first though. This might change with iOS 7.

Here is a similar question and answer for iOS 6:
[How can I upgrade iOS 6 beta to iOS 6 public release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500442/how-can-i-upgrade-ios-6-beta-to-ios6-public-release)

Comment: I can't download the beta though, I have to get it online?